# memset() doesn't initialize a dynamic array correctly

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-arrays, memset

I have a `matrix` class and there is a constructor like this:

```cpp
// m is the 2d array "T **m", r = no. of rows and c = no. of coumns
matrix<T>(int r, int c, T v = T()) : r(r), c(c) {
    m = new T*[r];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++) {
        m[i] = new T[c]();
        if(v != 0)
            std::memset(m[i], v, sizeof(T) * c);
    }
}
```

When I initialize like this,

```cpp
matrix<int> m(3,3);
std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

It works and I get the correct output,

```sh
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

But when I initialize with a non-default value,

```cpp
matrix<int> m(3,3,1);
std::cout << m << std::endl();
```

I get,

```sh
7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304 
7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304 
7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304 7.7486e-304
```

Although I was expecting this,

```sh
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Why?

Comment: memset() can only fill with a byte value.  The output doesn't look like `int` either, so you do have more than one bug.

Comment: `memset` probably isn't the tool you need here. Perhaps [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)? Mind you, can we talk you into `std::vector`? Reduce or eliminate a lot of headaches and will auto initialize to whatever you want.

Comment: To sum up these comments, you are filling the entire chunk of memory, viewed as bytes, with the low byte of `v`. You should be using `std:fill()` for this. `std::memset()` is definitely the wrong tool for this job.